# Why are packets being dropped (kfree_skb)?

Tags: networking, buffer, packet, traffic

I am currently sending ~9mpps, each packet is 72bytes large, and is a UDP DNS request. The packets are being sent to a Dell server I have using an intel i40e interface. The server is using all of its 32 queues and has a queue size of 4096 per queue. All client source packets have random source MAC addresses and random IP addresses in a pool of about 150. Note, that none of the network cards show dropped / discarded packets.

I can see all the unicast traffic is arriving to the interface `ethtool -S` shows `rx_unicast` at ~9mpps. However `rx_packets` shows 1.7mpps. The egress interface shows the same amount of packets being processed and sent out the other interface I am forwarding through. Note the far end IP the generated traffic arrives at is just a L3 interface, there are no DNS services listening on it, so the packets are dropped on the far end (this is ok).

When I use `dropwatch` I can see the following messages:

```
224021 drops at kfree_skb+1e (0xffffffffa33f5cbe) [software]
235277 drops at kfree_skb+1e (0xffffffffa33f5cbe) [software]
232467 drops at kfree_skb+1e (0xffffffffa33f5cbe) [software]
227083 drops at kfree_skb+1e (0xffffffffa33f5cbe) [software]
228235 drops at kfree_skb+1e (0xffffffffa33f5cbe) [software]
227216 drops at kfree_skb+1e (0xffffffffa33f5cbe) [software]
221967 drops at kfree_skb+1e (0xffffffffa33f5cbe) [software]
225418 drops at kfree_skb+1e (0xffffffffa33f5cbe) [software]
```

I tried looking up what `0xffffffffa33f5cbe` is in `/boot/System.map-$(uname -r)` but nothing is listed. I tried looking up what kfree_skb does, but [this](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/networking/API-kfree-skb.html) it frees the sk_buff memory. (not very helpful)

I believe this maybe a limitation of the kernel (forwarding, netfilter, etc.), or CPU being able to process so much traffic, however I would like to know why / and demonstrate the reason why packets are being dropped in the Kernel.

How can I determine why all traffic is not being sent?

**UPDATE**
I was able to remove the following modules

```
nf_conntrack
ip_tables
iptables_filter
x_tables
```

This increased the speed to processing more, I can see now I am able to send ~4.5mpps, it seems that netfilter is the bottle neck. Will work more with removing other modules. Curious if anyone else have details on why this happens?

Comment: What about CPU load (sys load especially)?

Comment: CPU load is slammed on all cores with ksoftirq interrupts. This is expected due every packet off the rx ring buffer added to the sk_buff ring buffer. I monitor this with the following command `watch -n1 'mpstat -u -I SUM -P ALL 1 1| egrep -v Aver` I also can see softirq increment in the first column of `/proc/net/softnet_stat`, This is also seen in `/proc/softirqs` for RX/TX columns. Note after removing the nf_conntrack module I no longer see the `/proc/net/softnet_stat` 3rd column (time squeeze) increment.